# SQLite delete column

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sqlite

I use this code form rename column or other:

```
BEGIN;
PRAGMA writable_schema = 1;
UPDATE SQLITE_MASTER SET SQL = replace(SQL, '[id] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY', '[id] INTEGER') WHERE NAME = 'test_table';
PRAGMA writable_schema = 0;
COMMIT;
```

But I can't delete:

```
BEGIN;
PRAGMA writable_schema = 1;
UPDATE SQLITE_MASTER SET SQL = replace(SQL, '[id] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY', 'DELETE THIS COLUMN') WHERE NAME = 'test_table';
PRAGMA writable_schema = 0;
COMMIT;
```

This code I know:) Don't offer.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1_backup(a,b);
INSERT INTO t1_backup SELECT a,b FROM t1;
DROP TABLE t1;
CREATE TABLE t1(a,b);
INSERT INTO t1 SELECT a,b FROM t1_backup;
DROP TABLE t1_backup;
COMMIT;
```

**Edit:**
I found!

```
BEGIN;
PRAGMA writable_schema = 1;
UPDATE SQLITE_MASTER SET SQL = replace(SQL, '[id] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY**,**', '') WHERE NAME = 'test_table';
PRAGMA writable_schema = 0;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: You can answer your own question and mark it...

Answer (score 2):

```
BEGIN;
PRAGMA writable_schema = 1;
UPDATE SQLITE_MASTER SET SQL = replace(SQL, '[id] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY**,**', '') WHERE NAME = 'test_table';
PRAGMA writable_schema = 0;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: This works only for the `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column.